# What does the dollar sign do in Swift / SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding, combine, property-wrapper

[This tutorial by Apple about SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input) uses a dollar sign to bind data, and I‘m having trouble finding more information about this data binding in SwiftUI.

```
Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
```

> You use the $ prefix to access a binding to a state variable, or one of its properties.

Is this some sort of `inout` type parameter? That uses the ampersand to pass it on.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `$` is used in conjunction with property wrappers (previously known as "property delegates").

It's **not an operator**, but a **prefix** (thanks @matt!).

For more about property delegates, see this Swift Evolution [document](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md).

e.g. in `@State var aState = false`, `State` is a property wrapper.

This means that if we write:

- `aState` we're accessing a `Bool` value
- `$aState` we're accessing a `Binding<Bool>` value

Different property delegates will generate different values, called "projected values".

Comment: You make it sound like some kind of operator. It isn't. The dollar sign is merely the first letter of the variable name. It doesn't "make" a binding. `$aState` _is_ the binding.

Comment: The `Binding` value should be `projectedValue`, right?

Comment: Also docs has a nice example in
`Projecting a Value From a Property Wrapper` at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

Comment: @Itachi yes, `projectedValue` of @State property wrapper has type `Binding`

Comment: I am now seeing `_aState` for `@State` and `@Binding` variables, what does it mean? As far as I can see, the underscore does the same as the dollar sign.

Comment: @matt 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published/projectedvalue
"The projectedValue is the property accessed with the $ operator." 
What's the "operator"?

Answer (score 92):

This is very well explained in [WWDC 2019 video 415](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/415/). You are merely looking at one special case of a broad language feature, namely property wrappers.

A property wrapper (such as `@State`) is actually a way of referring to an instance of a type (usually a struct or enum) with the same name (such as State). The latter provides instructions for turning this instance property into a computed property whose getter and setter are the getter and setter for a certain computed property of itself (its `wrappedValue`). It also typically holds private storage backing that computed property.

Thus, after the declaration

```
@State var showFavoritesOnly = true
```

...`showFavoritesOnly` is turned into a computed property, with its getter and setter supplied by the State struct. When you set `showFavoritesOnly` to true, that is routed through the State struct's setter and ends up in a stored property of the State instance.

All of this implies that somewhere there *is* a State instance associated with your `showFavoritesOnly`. And there is, but it's hidden from view. Its name, in case you'd like to see that State instance, is `_showFavoritesOnly`.

Okay, but when you say `$showFavoritesOnly`, you do *not* get a State struct; you get a Binding struct. Why? That's because a property wrapper has a mechanism for specifying what the returned value from the `$` name should be. In the case of State, it specifies that this value should be its own `binding` property, which is a Binding (see the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state).

By an amazing coincidence, Toggle's `isOn` initializer *takes* a Binding (again, see the docs, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toggle/3232112-init). You could not have set the Toggle's `isOn` to `showFavoritesOnly` even if you wanted to! Instead, you set it to the `Binding<Bool>` supplied by the State instance, so that the Toggle has automatic two-way communication with the State object. The SwiftUI framework enforces its own correct usage; a Toggle can exist *only* in relation to some binding that acts as the underlying source of truth for its on/off state. And because it's a binding, not a mere Bool, communication works in both directions: when the user taps the switch in the Toggle, the change in value flows "up" to the State variable by way of the binding.

Comment: Neat! The referenced video is here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/415/

Comment: Specifically, the property wrapper part of the talk starts at 23:30 ^