# How does $ work in SwiftUI and why can I cast a @StateObject to an @ObservedObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject

I'm a newbie developing an app which basically has a fridge class, which contains food. I'm trying to have one single fridge with a list of food. So I set **foodList** to be a published object and instantiate a @StateObject fridge when the program starts. Basically, from my perspective, whenever the **foodList** changes, the fridge object will save its state and give me a new view.

In addition, I want to pass this @StateObject fridge to another view so that my another view could modify my **foodList** in fridge

Below is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var fridge=Fridge();
    private var dbStartWith=0;
    
    @State private var selection = 1;
    @State private var addFood = false;
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            NavigationView {
                List(fridge.container!){
                    food in NavigationLink(destination: FoodView()) {
                        Text("HI")
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Fridge Items"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                        NavigationLink(destination: AddFoodView(fridgeView: fridge)) {
                                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle").resizable().frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                        } )
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Home")
            }
            .tag(1)
            
            
            Text("random tab")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "bookmark.circle.fill")
                    Text("profile")
                }
                .tag(0)
        }
        
    }
}
    

struct FoodView: View{
    var body: some View{
        NavigationView{
            Text("food destination view ");
        }
    }
}

struct AddFoodView: View{
    @ObservedObject var fridgeView: Fridge;
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var count : String = "1"
    @State private var category : String = "肉类";
    @State var showCategory = false
    @State var showCount = false
    

    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                Form{
                    HStack{
                        Text("食品")
                        TextField("请输入材料名", text: $name);
                    }.padding(.bottom,10).padding(.top,10).padding(.leading,10).padding(.trailing,10)
                    HStack{
                        Text("数量")
                        TextField("请选择数量",text:$count,onEditingChanged:{(changed) in
                            self.hideKeyboard();
                            self.showCount=changed;
                        }){}
                    }.padding(.bottom,10).padding(.top,10).padding(.leading,10).padding(.trailing,10)
                    HStack{
                        Text("种类")
                        TextField("请选择种类",text: $category,onEditingChanged:{(changed) in
                            self.hideKeyboard();
                            self.showCategory=changed;
                        }){}
                    }.padding(.bottom,10).padding(.top,10).padding(.leading,10).padding(.trailing,10)
                }
            }.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: FoodView()){
                Text("保存").foregroundColor(Color.blue).font(.system(size: 18,design: .default))
            }).simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                var tempFood=Food(id: fridgeView);//not completed yet
            })
            ZStack{
                    if self.showCount{
                        Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                            .opacity(0.5)
                        VStack(){
                            Spacer(minLength: 0);
                            HStack{
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.showCount=false;
                                }, label: {
                                    Text("Done")
                                }).frame(alignment: .trailing).offset(x:-15,y:15)
                            }
                            Picker(selection: $count,label: EmptyView()) {
                                ForEach(1..<100){ number in
                                    Text("\(number)").tag("\(number)")
                                }
                            }.labelsHidden()
                        }            .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: 300, minHeight: 250, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .top).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).fill(Color.white.opacity(1)))
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                        .offset(x:10,y:-10)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    if self.showCategory{
                        let categoryArr = ["肉类","蔬菜类","饮料类","调味品类"]
                        ZStack{
                            Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                                .opacity(0.5)
                            VStack(){
                                Spacer(minLength: 0);
                                HStack{
                                    Spacer()
                                    Button(action: {
                                        self.showCategory=false;
                                    }, label: {
                                        Text("Done")
                                    }).frame(alignment: .trailing).offset(x:-15,y:15)
                                }
                                Picker(selection: $category,label: EmptyView()) {
                                    ForEach(0..<categoryArr.count){ number in
                                        Text(categoryArr[number]).tag(categoryArr[number])
                                    }
                                }.labelsHidden()
                            }            .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: 300, minHeight: 250, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 250, alignment: .top).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).fill(Color.white.opacity(1)))
                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 27).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
                            Spacer()
                        }.offset(x:10,y:20)
                    }
            }
        }.animation(.easeInOut)
    }
        
    
}
```

Basically I want to pass the `@StateObject private var fridge` to the `struct AddFoodView: View` so that my `AddFoodView` can use the variable. From what I learned online, I think I need to inject `@ObservedObjects` like this `NavigationLink(destination: AddFoodView(fridgeView: fridge))`. This doesn't give me error ( at least in debugger phase) which confuses me. Isn't `fridge` a `Food` variable and  `fridgeView` a `@ObservedObject Food` variable ?

If I do something like this `AddFoodView(fridgeView: $fridge))`. There is an error saying `Cannot convert value '$fridge' of type 'ObservedObject<Fridge>.Wrapper' to expected type 'Fridge', use wrapped value instead`

Comment: *which confuses me* - why? It is injected correctly. Both StateObject and ObservedObject are wrappers for ObservableObject.

Comment: This might help you: [What does the dollar sign do in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56551131/8697793) and [What is the difference between ObservedObject and StateObject in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62544115/8697793)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@StateObject` and `@ObservedObject` are sources of truth, they are very similar to each other and almost interchangeable.

To share these with other `View`s you should pass it to  the `AddFoodView` using `.environmentObject(fridge)` and change the `@ObservedObject var fridgeView: Fridge;` in `AddFoodView` to `@EnvironmentObject var fridgeView: Fridge`.

Look up the Apple Documentation on ["Managing Model Data in Your App"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).

```
struct BookReader: App {
    @StateObject var library = Library()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
        LibraryView()
                .environmentObject(library)
        }
    }
}

struct LibraryView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var library: Library

    // ...
}
```

Another good source are the Apple SwiftUI Tutorials, especially ["Handling User Input"](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input)