# Pass an @State variable as parameter and change its value inside a function

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to validate textFields to only allow numbers, a single period, or a single comma. In the code below I have two `TextField`s, `textFieldOne` and `textFieldTwo`, in `textFieldOne` I'm validating the field by calling the `validateField()` method, everything works as expected for textFieldOne since I'm modifying its value inside the `validateField()` method, but what I'm trying to do is make the `validateField()` method more modular and be able to pass a `State` variable to be able to use it with multiple fields to avoid code duplication but I haven't been able to figure out a way to pass the `State` variable as a parameter in the `validateField()` method. I tried passing it as `validateField(textFieldName: Binding<String> ,newValue:String)` but I got errors saying that it couldn't convert `type 'String' to expected type 'Binding<String>`.

How can I pass `@State` textFieldOne and textFieldOne respectably as a parameter in the `validateField()` method?

Again, what I'm trying to do is be able to call the `validateField()` method inside the `.onChange` modifier of each field, something like this... `validateField(fieldName:textFieldOne, newValue: newValue)`. Basically, make the method reusable.

```
    struct TextFieldNumbersOnly: View {
        @State private var textFieldOne = ""
        @State private var textFieldTwo = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            Form{
                TextField("field one", text: $textFieldOne)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .onChange(of: textFieldOne){newValue in
                        validateField(newValue: newValue)
                    }
                
                TextField("field two", text: $textFieldTwo)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    .onChange(of: textFieldTwo){newValue in
                        //validateField(newValue: newValue)
                    }
            }

        }
        
        func validateField(newValue:String){
            let periodCount = newValue.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1
            let commaCount = newValue.components(separatedBy: ",").count - 1
            
            if newValue.last == "." && periodCount > 1 || newValue.last == "," && commaCount > 1{
                //it's a second period or comma, remove it
                textFieldOne = String(newValue.dropLast())
            }else{
                let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.,".contains($0) }
                if filtered != newValue{
                    self.textFieldOne = filtered
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A “bare” access to a state variable just reads out its currently value. To pass a binding, you need to prefix it with `$`. (This accesses the `projectedValue` of a property wrapper, [which for `@State` is a Binding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/projectedvalue).) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551131/what-does-the-dollar-sign-do-in-swift-swiftui

Comment: Oh, the docs for State explain this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/projectedvalue

Comment: Ah, that makes sense but when I pass it as  `validateField(fieldName: $textFieldTwo)` I get error, `Cannot assign to value: 'fieldName' is a 'let' constant` when I try to assign a new value inside the `validateField` methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this alternative approach, to achieve what you want, `...to validate textFields to only allow numbers, a single period, or a single comma`
and to make the function `validateField(...)` more modular.

The approach simply uses a modified function `validateField(...)` that
returns the validated String, as shown in the example code.
It's clean and do what the function is supposed to do,
take a `String` input and returns a validated one as output.

```
struct TextFieldNumbersOnly: View {
    @State private var textFieldOne = ""
    @State private var textFieldTwo = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("field one", text: $textFieldOne)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .onChange(of: textFieldOne){ newValue in
                    textFieldOne = validateField(newValue) // <-- here
                }
            
            TextField("field two", text: $textFieldTwo)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .onChange(of: textFieldTwo){ newValue in
                    textFieldTwo = validateField(newValue) // <-- here
                }
        }
    }

    func validateField(_ newValue: String) -> String {  // <-- here
        let periodCount = newValue.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1
        let commaCount = newValue.components(separatedBy: ",").count - 1
        
        if newValue.last == "." && periodCount > 1 || newValue.last == "," && commaCount > 1 {
            //it's a second period or comma, remove it
            return String(newValue.dropLast())  // <-- here
        } else {
            let filtered = newValue.filter { "0123456789.,".contains($0) }
            if filtered != newValue{
                return filtered // <-- here
            }
        }
        return newValue // <-- here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new View and put one TextField and the validation in it. FYI SwiftUI is designed to do validation in onSubmit instead of onChange to allow pasting. Then use two of these Views.

```
TextFieldNumbersOnly(text: $one)
TextFieldNumbersOnly(text: $two)

struct TextFieldNumbersOnly: View {
    @Binding private var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TextField("field", text: $text)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            .onSubmit {
                validate()
            }
    }
            
    func validate(){
…
```

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not fully understanding your suggestion about creating a new view... I like the idea of allowing pasting but using onCommint the validation won't happen until the user moves to a different field.

Comment: @fs_tigre pretty simple and the way SwiftUI is designed, I added some code to show you

Comment: Sorry I thought it was the op’s validation code, I removed it

Comment: Everyone has made copy and paste errors at some point.